# It seems I can't write the right xPath to get the results I need

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm trying to write a Xpath to retrieve portion of data from a XML file, but get only the first degree text-value, and not the whole node-tree I need.

I'm using a dynamic XML file from this address -

```
https://ims.data.gov.il/sites/default/files/IMS_001.xml
```

containing weather forecasts for 10 locations.

A partial sample of the data looks like this:

```
<HourlyLocationsForecast>
<Identification>
<Organization>Israel Meteorological Service</Organization>
<Title>Hourly forecasts for selected locations</Title>
<IssueDateTime>Tue Dec 10 06:30:40 IST 2019</IssueDateTime>
</Identification>
<Location>...</Location>
<Location>...</Location>
<Location>...</Location>
<Location>...</Location>
<Location>...</Location>
<Location>...</Location>
<Location>...</Location>
<Location>
<LocationMetaData>
<LocationName>JERUSALEM CENTRE</LocationName>
<LocationLatitude>31.781</LocationLatitude>
<LocationLongitude>35.222</LocationLongitude>
<LocationHeight>810</LocationHeight>
</LocationMetaData>
<LocationData>
<Forecast>
<ForecastTime>10/12/2019 04:00 UTC</ForecastTime>
<Temperature>10.8</Temperature>
<RelativeHumidity>92</RelativeHumidity>
<WindSpeed>2.2</WindSpeed>
<WindDirection>223</WindDirection>
</Forecast>
<Forecast>
<ForecastTime>10/12/2019 05:00 UTC</ForecastTime>
<Temperature>11.0</Temperature>
<RelativeHumidity>91</RelativeHumidity>
<WindSpeed>2.2</WindSpeed>
<WindDirection>226</WindDirection>
</Forecast>
<Forecast>
<ForecastTime>10/12/2019 06:00 UTC</ForecastTime>
<Temperature>11.1</Temperature>
<RelativeHumidity>90</RelativeHumidity>
<WindSpeed>2.2</WindSpeed>
<WindDirection>229</WindDirection>
</Forecast>
</LocationData>
</Location>
<Location>...</Location>
</HourlyLocationsForecast>
```

I want to extract the data for 1 location, the 8th in the sequence.
So, I tried to write this Xpath:

```
/HourlyLocationsForecast/Location[8]/*
```

I'm trying to get all the data for that location. Instead, I'm getting just the location parameters, without the forecasts that are under its level.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You haven't shown how you are applying the XPath or how you are using the results, it it's still difficult to answer or diagnose your issue. However, try selecting just the `Location` element with the XPath `/HourlyLocationsForecast/Location[8]` and assign it to a variable, then you can further interrogate that element to snag the `LocationMetadata` or the `LocationData/Forecast` info.

Comment: @MadsHansen Thank you so much for that!
You`re right I didn`t mention the way I`m implementing this. I`m using a software tool (Automate BPA Server), and I`m just interested in the proper way to write the XPath.
The difference you told me (omitting that last `/` so not need for the `*`) made a big different, so now I`m going to manipulate the more-informative value I have.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you are looking for, but this expression

```
(/HourlyLocationsForecast/Location/LocationData/Forecast)[8]/descendant::*/text()
```

Outputs this:

> 08/07/2019 06:00 UTC
>
> 28.0
>
> 67
>
> 2.1
>
> 227

Is that your intended target?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not that.
It seems that the [8] in your example refers to forecast 8, and I need location 8.

Comment: @Offer - So what exactly is your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct xpath to get all the nodes under 8th location

```
/HourlyLocationsForecast/Location[8]/descendant::*
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

## =====================================================

If you want the text from each node then you can use the below.

/HourlyLocationsForecast/Location[8]/descendant::*/text()

**Screenshot:**

[image]